# Outlook VBA: Items.Count is overflowing when trying to loop backwards through a collection of appointments to delete them

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to create a macro that will delete all Appointments from the outlook calendar that have the subject 'Move to Marketing Questionnaire'. I followed [this instruction from microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/how-to/search-and-filter/search-the-calendar-for-appointments-within-a-date-range-that-contain-a-specific) to find and list all of the appointments that I'm looking for, but when I go to delete them I know that I have to switch from a `For each` loop to a `For` loop and loop backwards due to the way collections are indexed, otherwise the code misses some appointments.

When I make this change, the for loop is failing because the index is an Integer and the output of the Debug.print oItemsWithSubjectRange.Count is (overflowing?) to 2147483647. **Is there a different command to get the number of appointments found with the two filters I've applied?**

I'm expecting this macro to need to delete up to 50 appointments at the absolute max (normally 10-20) so an Integer *should* be sufficient for my needs.

Here is my code - I have included the original `For each` loop at the bottom (commented) which is able to *print* the right appointments that I want to delete, but when I run the code it misses some appointments. The `For` loop above it is causing `Runtime error 6: Overflow` errors.

```vb
Sub deleteMoveToMarketing()

    Dim myStart As Date
    Dim myEnd As Date
    Dim oCalendar As Outlook.Folder
    Dim oItems As Outlook.Items
    Dim oItemsWithDateRange As Outlook.Items
    Dim oItemsWithSubjectRange As Outlook.Items
    Dim oAppt As Outlook.AppointmentItem
    Dim strRestriction As String
    Dim i As Integer

    myStart = Date - 30
    myEnd = Date

    Debug.Print "Start:", myStart
    Debug.Print "End:", myEnd

    'Construct filter for the next 30-day date range
    strRestriction = "[Start] >= '" & _
    Format$(myStart, "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm AMPM") _
    & "' AND [End] <= '" & _
    Format$(myEnd, "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm AMPM") & "'"
    'Check the restriction string
    Debug.Print strRestriction

    Set oCalendar = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)
    Set oItems = oCalendar.Items
    oItems.IncludeRecurrences = True
    oItems.Sort "[Start]"
    'Restrict the Items collection for the date range
    Set oItemsWithDateRange = oItems.Restrict(strRestriction)

    'Construct filter for the subject restriction
    strRestriction = "[Subject] = 'Move to Marketing Questionnaire'"
    'Check the restriction string
    Debug.Print strRestriction

    'Restrict the Items collection for the date range
    Set oItemsWithSubjectRange = oItemsWithDateRange.Restrict(strRestriction)

    'Construct filter for Subject containing 'team'
    Debug.Print oItemsWithSubjectRange.Count
    For i = oItemsWithSubjectRange.Count To 1 Step -1
        Debug.Print oItemsWithSubjectRange(i).Start, oItemsWithSubjectRange(i).Subject
        'oItemsWithSubjectRange(i).Delete
    Next


    'For Each oAppt In oItemsWithSubjectRange
        'Debug.Print oAppt.Start, oAppt.Subject
        'oAppt.Delete
    'Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, Items.Count returns -1 because the collection does not know how many items are there unless it expands all recurring activities.

Since occurrences are included, you end up deleting instances of recurring activities (which do not physically exists as real items). This may or may not be what you want

Comment: Thank you! I have set `oItems.IncludeRecurrences = False` in the above code - these appointments are auto-generated individually and are not recurring anyway.
`oItemsWithSubjectRange.Count` is now returning `7` and when I uncommented the Delete command the macro is working as expected.
Thanks again - I marked this answer as accepted.